# What to do *rigorously* when the second derivative test is inconclusive?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

How do you **rigorously** check if a point is a local minimum when the second derivative test is inconclusive?
Does there exist a way to do this in general for arbitrary smooth (or analytic...) functions?

I know I can graph the function, plug in a few values, etc. (there are lots of questions with these as answers) but that's not rigorous. I'm wondering what I would do in a rigorous proof -- I don't think I ever learned this.

Comment: You look at higher derivatives. Let me stick to one variable for simplicity. If the smallest $k$ such that the $k^{th}$ derivative is nonzero is odd then the point is neither a local minimum nor a local maximum. If the smallest $k$ is even then apply the second derivative test to that derivative. (Exercise.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan we should specify that this is guaranteed to work for analytic functions (I don't believe smoothness is sufficient).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That's a nice answer whenever it works, but what about flat functions (like $x \to e^{-x^{-2}}$)? Is there anything we can do about those?

Comment: @Mehrdad: if all derivatives vanish at a point then you just need to look at the function and see what you can say about it. By assumption there's nothing you can say involving just derivatives. In the specific case you give you know how $e^x$ behaves and you know how $-x^{-2}$ behaves so it's not so bad.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: So in other words there's no rigorous method that works for all (smooth) cases?

Comment: Arbitrary smooth functions can be pretty arbitrary so it's unclear what "rigorous method that works for all cases" even means here. Certainly I can rigorously tell you, at any $x$, whether $e^{-x^{-2}}$ has a local minimum or maximum or whatever, by thinking about how $e^x$ and $-x^{-2}$ behave. It's not as if it's nonrigorous to use different methods in different situations.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Er, I mean is there no generic algorithm for deciding this for all smooth functions?

Comment: @Mehrdad: that depends on what kind of inputs you're expecting such an algorithm to take, but I think the answer is no. IIRC there already isn't an algorithm for deciding whether an elementary function (which is smooth on its domain) is identically zero or not.

Comment: I think this is what you're actually looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for functions of one variable. First, a comment. The second derivative test is often not the best approach. For one thing, it involves computing and evaluating the second derivative. That involves work, and carries a non-zero probability of error.

In many of the usual calculus problems, the right approach is to look at the behaviour of the *first* derivative near the critical point. If the first derivative is non-positive in an interval $(a-\epsilon,a)$ of the critical point $a$, and non-negative in an interval $(a,a+\epsilon)$, then we have a local minimum at $a$.

Now assume that $f$ is *analytic* in an interval about the critical point $a$. Let $k$ be the smallest integer $\ge 2$ such that $f^{(k)}(a)\ne 0$. If $k$ is even, and 
$f^{(k)}(a)\gt 0$, then we have a local minimum at $a$. If $k$ is even, and 
$f^{(k)}(a)\lt 0$, then we have a local minimum at $a$. If $k$ is odd, we have neither a local maximum nor a local minimum at $x=a$.

Comment: How do you rigorously tell if the first derivative is non-positive in an interval $(a - \epsilon, a)$? Of course we can graph the function, but that's not rigorous.

Comment: Well, every problem is different, but let us take $f(x)=x^2-6x+1$. Then $f'(x)=2(x-3)$, and it is clear that $f'(x)\lt 0$ if $x\lt 3$ and $f(x)\gt 0$ if $x\gt 3$. I have cheated by taking a very simple example, but in many standard applications of the calculus, the calculation is not significantly harder. For example, when we differentiate a quotient, the denominator is a square, safely positive. To examine the sign of the derivative, all we need to do is examine the sign of the numerator, which is often easy. By contrast, the second derivative can be a bit of a mess.

Comment: To follow-up on André Nicolas' comment, my experience in teaching for many years has been that the use of sign charts along with the first derivative test is often easier than the second derivative test, and it gives MUCH MORE information than the second derivative test. See [this 29 October 2006](http://mathforum.org/kb/plaintext.jspa?messageID=5324603) sci.math post for a wide variety of examples in which sign charts are used along with the first derivative test.